# Getting 2 different decrypted values from very similar AES implementation using cryptoJS (getting a wrong result value for the 16th char)

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I am trying to implement a encryption helper for a project. These are the cryptoJS versions I am using:

```
 <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js</script>
 <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha1.js">
```

And this is how I implemented:

```
var security = function () { };

security.sha1 = function (word) {
    var result = CryptoJS.SHA1(word);
    return result.toString().toUpperCase();
};

security.encrypt = function (content, key, iv) {
    if (key.length != 16) {
        console.error('Use chave de 16 digitos');
        return;
    }
    content = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(content);
    key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('1234567812345670');

    var options = {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        iv: iv
    };

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(content, key, options);

    return encrypted;
};

security.decrypt = function (message, key, iv) {
    if (key.length != 16) {
        console.error('Use chave de 16 digitos');
        return;
    }

    key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv)

    var options = {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        iv: iv
    };
    var result = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(message, key, options);

    return result;
};


$(document).ready(function () {

    var original = "texto#a$ser&criptografado! ! ! !";
    var hash = security.sha1('blablablabla');
    var key = hash.substring(0, 16);
    var iv = '1234567812345678';

    var crypto = security.encrypt(original, key, iv);
    var dcrypt = security.decrypt(crypto, key, iv);

    alert('  original: ' + original+
          '\n\n     sha-1: ' + hash+
          '\n\n       key: ' + key+
          '\n\n resultado: ' + crypto+
          '\n\n     final: ' + dcrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

        });
```

The problem is that I am getting this strange result:

> original: texto#a$ser&criptografado! ! ! !
>
> ```
>  final: texto#a$ser&crixtografado! ! ! !
> ```

It always change the 16th char of the original text. ([Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5Cuvv/4/) is a jsfiddle for this test)

And here is another test, with the same lib versions, that is working correctly:

```
var cryptHelper = function(key,iv){if(key!=undefined&&iv!=undefined)this.initForEncryption(key,iv)};

cryptHelper.prototype = {

    key:null,
    iv:null,
    options: null,

    sha1: function(message){
        console.log('message = '+message);
        var result = CryptoJS.SHA1(message);
        return result.toString().toUpperCase();
    },

initForEncryption: function(key,iv){
    if(key!=undefined&&iv!=undefined){
        this.setKey(key);
        this.setIv(iv);
        this.setOptions();
    }else{
        throw new Error('null keyOrIv error');
    }
},

    setKey: function(key){
        if(key!=undefined){
            if (key.length != 16)
                throw new Error('Use chave de 16 digitos');
            else
                this.key=CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
        }
        else if(this.key == undefined)
            throw new Error('nullEncryptionKeyException');
    },

    setIv:function(iv){
        if(iv!=undefined){
            if (iv.length != 16)
                throw new Error('Use iv de 16 digitos');
            else
                this.iv=CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);
        }
        else if(this.iv == undefined)
            throw new Error('nullIvException');
    },

    setOptions: function(){
        this.options = {mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
                        iv: this.iv }
    },

    encryptEAS: function(message){
        this.checkValues();
        return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message), this.key, this.options);
    },

    decryptEAS: function(message){
        this.checkValues();
        return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(message, this.key, this.options);
    },

    checkValues: function(){
        if(this.key==undefined || this.iv==undefined)
            throw new Error('method unavailable! please init the crypthelper');
    }
};

var testeCriptografia = function(){
    var helper = new cryptHelper();

    var original = "texto#a$ser&criptografado! ! ! !";
    var hash = helper.sha1('blablablabla');
    var key = hash.substring(0, 16);
    var iv = '1234567812345678';

    helper.initForEncryption(key,iv);

    var crypto = helper.encryptEAS(original);
    var dcrypt = helper.decryptEAS(crypto);

    alert('  original: ' + original+
          '\n\n     sha-1: ' + hash+
          '\n\n       key: ' + key+
          '\n\n resultado: ' + crypto+
          '\n\n     final: ' + dcrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    testeCriptografia();
});
```

([Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HWHx8/3/) is the jsfiddle for the 2nd version)

The problem is that I dont know why the 2nd version is working and the first one isnt.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong in the first one, or if my implementation is all wrong in both versions.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that using keys derived from ASCII strings is not very secure. The initialization vector should also be different every time the encryption function is called. Finally, please see this article: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: Thanks @ntoskrnl! Good to know. And I appreciate the article. It does have a lot of useful tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you are using `123456781234567**0**` instead of `123456781234567**8**` in your encrypt method.

Comment: Thanks man! I am felling quite stupid now! I guess this is what I get from spending hours using the computer. HAHAHAHA Sometimes all we need is someone from outside to take a quick look! Thanks dude!